Splitting Grouped Features in QGIS or other Software
I have Shape file consisting of the US census divisions. There are 9 divisions as shown in the pic below. I just want to get a shape file consisting of mainland US regions only. This basically means deleting Alaska, Hawaii and a few oceanic island but keeping califonia, oregan and wahsington states. However I am unable to do this as the shapefile has grouped all of these states into one specific region called pacific.
Any clue how I can split them and save it as new shape file which contains only mainland US census division ? Or is this even possible ?
I am good with python/shell based solutions as well but ideally QGIS would make it easier


Yes, select the ones you want https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvUcwK0fXZM and then export to a new shape file https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6q73HM_8M2Q, you may need to break multipart features if they're merged https://mapscaping.com/split-multipolygons-into-single-polygons-in-qgis/

You can either:
1a) apply the "Multipart to singleparts" processing algorithm to the layer
1b) delete the unwanted feature's geometries from the output of 1a
1c) if needed, dissolve the features based on the field "NAME"
or:
2a) use the "Delete part" map tool to delete the unwanted geometry parts from the layer

This is the answer you'll want to follow.
